# Airflow - Not able to delete dag

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am trying following command to delete a DAG, however getting following error.

**Command**

```
 airflow delete_dag example_http_operator
```

**Error**:

```
File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 588, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: dag
[SQL: SELECT dag.dag_id AS dag_dag_id, dag.root_dag_id AS dag_root_dag_id, dag.is_paused AS dag_is_paused, dag.is_subdag AS dag_is_subdag, dag.is_active AS dag_is_active, dag.last_scheduler_run AS dag_last_scheduler_run, dag.last_pickled AS dag_last_pickled, dag.last_expired AS dag_last_expired, dag.scheduler_lock AS dag_scheduler_lock, dag.pickle_id AS dag_pickle_id, dag.fileloc AS dag_fileloc, dag.owners AS dag_owners, dag.description AS dag_description, dag.default_view AS dag_default_view, dag.schedule_interval AS dag_schedule_interval
FROM dag
WHERE dag.dag_id = ?
 LIMIT ? OFFSET ?]
```

Comment: There is no need for double quotation. If you remove it and the error remains, check your dag name.

Comment: Same error. Dag exists. This is one of example dags. I tried on other dags as well.. Can't delete any

Comment: what Airflow environment you have?  on host machine? in docker?

Comment: On host machine. Amazone ec2 instance